# if() function inside the array() function

Tags: php, arrays, function, if-statement

I would like to do something like that:

```
 array(

if($condition = "xyz") { array('value' => $a, 'text' => $a), }
                         array('value' => $b, 'text' => $b),
                         ...
);
```

but it would not allow me to have that if function inside that array function? What I am doing wrong? Is there a way to make it possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must use if statements inside arrays, use shorthand ifs:

```
$arr = array(

    "xyz" == $condition  ?  array('value' => $a, 'text' => $a) : null, //null or whatever
    array('value' => $b, 'text' => $b),
                         ...

);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise your array and then add to it wherever you like:

```
$array = [];

if ($condition) {
    $array[] = ["value" => $a, "text" => $a];
}

$array[] = ["value" => $b, "test" => $b];
```

Comment: that would be quite difficult because that array is inside two other multiple arrays with the "=>" structure. Is there another solution?

Comment: @hillcode your example in your post does not indicate being inside 'multiple arrays'.  This perfectly satisfies your example given.

Answer (score 0):

The closest result that I believe you can achieve is by using a **ternary if condition**, and then filtering the empty items by using the `array_filter` function:

```
$array = array_filter(array(
    array('array1'),
    $condition ? array('array2') : null,
    array('array3)
));
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your use of array_filter here.

Comment: @Progrock Ofc. if `$condition == false`, an array item still will be created, even if you set it as `null`. In order to trim the empty item, use the `array_filter` function.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
$array = array_filter([
    $condition ? ['value' => 'aText', 'text' => 'aValue'] : null,
    ['value' => 'bValue', 'text' => 'bText']
]);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your use of array_filter here.

Comment: How does this differ to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59238660/3392762

Comment: Use array_filter to remove empty elements @Progrock